# Template <class = void*>, would appreciate an explanation

Tags: c++, templates, void-pointers

I am reading a book where the guy makes a linked list
he creates a class like this

```
template < class extra_info = void*>
class NavGraphNode : public GraphNode
{
protected:
//the node's position
Vector2D m_vPosition;

extra_info m_ExtraInfo;
public:
/*INTERFACE OMITTED */
};
```

He explains extra_info could be for example an enumerated value or a pointer
to the instance the node is twinned with. But I don't really understand the first line,
reading for example
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/
it seems that if you specify the type (and why not void* extra_info?)
then why use a template in the first place?

Thanks!

Comment: From the very page you linked to: "*It is also possible to set default values or types for class template parameters.*". That is what the `= void*` part is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`= void*` is a default template argument. I.e., if you do not specify a type when instanciating the template `void*` is used. `NavGraphNode<> n;` will instanciate the template using `void*` as extra info.

However, you CAN explicitly specify a type, then this type is used. E.g., you could use `NavGraphNode<int>` to add an integer as extra info to you graph node. You can also use whole structs or pointers to those to add more info to a node.

Comment: That was fast thanks! Perfect answer (it won't let me accept yet though)

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of an extension point if someone wants to store additional information in `NavGraphNode` class and can specify what type of information they would like to store.

```
NavGraphNode<bool> visitedNavGraphNode;
```

If a client of this class is not interested in storing any additional information, then the client can simply ignore and create a normal instance as follows:

```
NavGraphNode<> simpleNavGraphNode;
```